# Sum values from a calculated field in one table and insert it into another

Tags: sql, delphi

I need to fill in some information before I open a table but have no clue on how to write a query
that will do the required update.

I want to fetch the SUM of all hours from one table (lets call it Table1) WHERE Location = '3' and DATE = (the date I have in
my Table2 (the name of the table I want updated with data).
Something like :

```
UPDATE TABLE2 SET MYFIELD = SUM HOURS FROM TABLE1 where TABLE1.DATE = TABLE2.DATE AND LOCATION = '3';
```

The hours that are in my Table1 are a result of a calculated field so I dont know if the update will sum these values as it is not a persistent field. Please help ...

Comment: [try this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e248/1)

Comment: I just realized my logic was flawed....I can not operate from another table with calculated fields in a table as if they were normal fields.

Comment: :) , great that it was found :)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to adjust sql below based on your DB, below logic should work

```
UPDATE TABLE2
       JOIN (select date,sum(hours) totalhrs from TABLE1 where location='3' group by date) TABLE1
       ON TABLE1.DATE = TABLE2.DATE 
SET    TABLE2.MYFIELD = TABLE1.totalhrs
```